Is this a reference to a specific movie in the music video Troy of die fantastischen 4?
In the music-video "Troy" from the german band die "Die Fantastischen 4" they reference to some styles and movies of the past. I always wondered about the scene from 1:49 to 2:07, this reminds me of some movie i can not remember (maybe a french or german one from the 70s). Does somebody know to which movie this references, or ist this just made up without a real example?
link to video clip:
Troy
another link because first does not work in all countries:
Troy

Style looks like a French new wave movie with Bardot to me.

@walt: thought about something like this, did also remembered me at bardot, but did not know which movie it could be..

Is the video recreating specific scenes from movies? Or just general styles? (Haven't watched the full thing yet)

i guess both. There are some clear movie references (Rambo, gone with the wind or west side story), some i am not sure if they reference to a movie (maybe kir royal, path of glory and clockwork orange), and for some i think its only a reference to a style like hippies, 60 bands...But i have no idea of this specific scene, its looks so much like a movie reference, and it reminds of something famous i have seen somewhere some time ago, but i am not sure...

According to this message board entry, the scene is from some movie with Alain Delon: http://www.gamestar.de/community/gspinboard/archive/index.php/t-44321.html

Hm, that is interesting, i will check if there was a movie with alain delon and bridget bardot...

Here is only the scene in the bed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uWQiIzeKR0

Yes, but the part with the girl is missing. I looked through some movies of Alain Delon, but did not find something matching this scene. There are some pictures of him with cigarette and bathrobe in bed, but they are not from a movie. And the only film with also bardot in it, does not fit the scene...

It reminds me of the hotel scenes in "Breathless" but Jean Seberg had cropped hair, and the girl in the shot really does look like Bardot.
